# QTPLUGIN, what's the purpose of it?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

While studying the [Plug & Paint Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-example.html) I've noted there is no `QPLUGIN` in the [plugandpaint.pro](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-plugandpaint-pro.html) file.

In the [Static Plugins section of the "How to Create Qt Plugins"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins), I read "To link plugins statically, you need to add the required plugins to your build using QTPLUGIN."

So, what's going on here?

Experimentally, I commented `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(BasicToolsPlugin)` in the [main.cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-main-cpp.html) and added `QTPLUGIN += pnp_basictools` to the .pro file, as a result no plugins where loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation seems to be a bit misleading. This is my understanding of the `QTPLUGIN` qmake parameter:

`QTPLUGIN` can be used to specify a list of names of *Qt platform plugins* that are to be linked with an application when linking against **static** build of Qt. Examples of such plugins are image formats like qgif, qjpeg, qsvg, database support like qsqlite, qsqloci, qsqlpsql, some language codecs.

The variable has **no effect** when linking against a **dynamic** build of Qt.

Comment: @KubaOber, do you agree?